# How do I access this JSON-encoded value in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
 "userID": "2A8761E4-C13A-470E-A759-91432D61B6AF-25982-0000352D853511AF"
}
```

It is the return value from from an AFNetworking JSON request.  The object is called JSON.

I've tried to access the userID value several different ways but keep getting the error "Unrecognized selector".  Here's what I've tried:

```
[JSON objectForKey:@"userID"]
[JSON valueForKey:@"userID"]   
[[JSON objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"userID"];
[[JSON objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"userID"];
[JSON objectAtIndex[0]];
```

What is the correct syntax?

EDIT

Here's more detail on the Unrecognized Selector error.

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20068150
2013-02-23 15:58:13.993 BMTabbed[12312:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20068150'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x325032a3 0x3a22097f 0x32506e07 0x32505531 0x3245cf68 0xbe9ed 0xbe91b 0xaae8f 0xabe65 0x3a63811f 0x3a6374b7 0x3a63c1bd 0x324d6f3b 0x32449ebd 0x32449d49 0x360202eb 0x3435f301 0x96e95 0x3a657b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Of which class is `JSON`?

Comment: Can you put output from `NSLog(@"%@", JSON);`

Comment: @H2CO3 I think it's an NSHTTPUrlResponse object.  However, I could be mistaken.  I'm looking at the AFNetworking code to confirm.

Comment: @Paul.s Yes I can.  It prints exactly what I've shown as the contents of the object.

Comment: @hughesdan So what if you `NSLog(@"%s", object_getClass(JSON));`?

Comment: @H2CO3 It prints a strange string of characters "h.à:»-à:`,å<0ìV\ã<†-à:H€<,å<ªV\ã<\ã<H€<,å<ÔW|.à:Hã<Pa ,å<pÔW∏.à:ê.à:H€<,å<ÑŒá:\ã<|.à:H€<,å<ÿÕá:‡.à:Hã<H€<,å<x–á:\ã<\ã<H€<,å<0œá:/à:Hã<H€<,å<¯—á:\ã<\ã<H€<,å<¿–á:0/à:"

Comment: @H2CO3 any reason for the preference to jump down to `NSLog(@"%s", object_getClass(JSON));` over `NSLog(@"%@", [JSON class]);`? I would imagine the later is more accessible to newer objective-c programmers

Comment: Now we're talking.  It's a __NSCFDictionary if I use [JSON class].

Comment: @hughesdan Sorry, I meant `NSLog(@"%s", class_getName(object_getClass(JSON)));`

Comment: @Paul.s Yes, because `- description` can (and usually is) overridden.

Comment: @hughesdan If it's an `NSDictionary`, then it **does** respond to `objectForKey:`. What's the unrecognized selector and what object is it sent to?

Comment: @H2CO3 I wasn't using description? I used `[JSON class]`. I would imagine `class` is not really overridden much

Comment: @Paul.s the `%@` format specifier tells `NSLog()` to call `- description` on its corresponding argument (the class object in this case).

Comment: @H2CO3 I edited my question to provide more detail on the Unrecognized Selector.  As far as I can tell, it's sent to the NSCFDictionary object called JSON.

Comment: @H2CO3 have you come across any instances of someone actually overriding `+ (NSString *)description;` in the wild? I would imagine this would be fairly rare

Comment: @hughesdan I don't think `__NSCFString` is `NSDictionary`...

Comment: @Paul.s It's better to be safe. `description` is never to be relied upon, and I wanted to know the class name :)

Comment: @H2CO3 fair play :). @hughesdan either `[JSON objectForKey:@"userID"]` or `JSON[@"userID"]` should work. Is the JSON log above a copy and paster or typed in manually?

Comment: @Paul.s Neither one should work since it's an `NSString` and not an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @H2CO3 that was based on the previous `[JSON class] => __NSCFDictionary `. The OP does not specify which (of the many) code attempts threw that exception

Comment: @Paul.s I see. Yes, what he does is not very helpful... :(

Comment: @Paul.s The JSON log is copy pasted.  The error message was from when I attempted [JSON objectForKey:@"userID"].  JSON[@"userID"] fails too.

Comment: @hughesdan you said `[JSON class]` give you `__NSCFDictionary` and you also say `[JSON objectForKey:@"userID"]` throws `-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:` - they can't both be right????

Comment: @Paul.s Sorry, I was mistaken.  JSON[@"userID"] IS working.  Do you want to submit that as an answer? I learned a few things today from your comments and from those of H2CO3.  +1 to you both.  Thank you.

Comment: @hughesdan `[JSON objectForKey:@"userID"]` should also work fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
NSLog(@"%@", [JSON class]); //=> __NSCFDictionary
```

then either

```
[JSON objectForKey:@"userID"]
```

or

```
JSON[@"userID"]
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `NSDictionary` selectors to an `NSString`. You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert a JSON string to an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, depending on the root object of your JSON string. In your case it is an `NSDictionary`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
```